# How can I completely disable Code Coverage button on IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

Coverage button near the start and debug button is a bit annoying in IntelliJ. I cannot find a way to completely remove it. Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

You could remove it in "File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars - Main Toolbar - Toolbar RunActions - Run/Debug"

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. The issue tracking it can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183545

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks, I followed you instructions but the button is still there! I even restarted the application as well. I am using intelliJ 2017.2 community edition on a Mac.
What is the version you use?

Comment: I checked with 2018 version. Looks like a bug with 2017 version.

Comment: OK will check with latest 2018 edition. I thought the same (bug), I will let you know,  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Version 2019.2. Removed it in the toolbar dialog, but even after restarting it doesn't go away. Same problem with the "Run with profiler" button.